# CORS Headers appended to HTTP Response not Sent to Browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, cors

I am writing directly to the request headers in an ASP.NET MVC via the `HttpContext.Current` object and yet these headers are not being sent to the browser... Any idea what could cause this? I ONLY get the headers if I add them via the web.config. This does not work for me as I need to allow multiple domains to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

I attempted to write the headers directly to `HttpContext.Current` using this code.

```
context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
context.Response.Write("Hello World " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

I get the hello world but not the headers.

I have also attempted to use `Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Http.Cors.WebApi` but get the same results, which is nothing. I have checked an rechecked my code to be sure it conforms to the tutorial][1](http://brockallen.com/2012/06/28/cors-support-in-webapi-mvc-and-iis-with-thinktecture-identitymodel/). I have configured the headers in the Web.config and attempted via Thinktecture however I only get the headers when `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is in the web.config but I still get an error in Chrome/FF. It seems like the headers are only being sent on the OPTIONS request but I am not certain.

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ga;q=0.6,pt-BR;q=0.4,pt;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, origin, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Authorization:Negotiate REDACTED
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:bpapi.domain.com
Origin:http://dev-02
Referer:http://dev-02/_Layouts/PAR/NewParItem.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Persistent-Auth: false
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://dev-02
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate REDACTED
Date: Sat, 06 Apr 2013 00:35:31 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Here is the [web.config as a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/AjGLwtLj) so as not to clutter up the question. WebDAV is ***not*** installed.

```
public class CorsConfig
{
    public static void RegisterCors(HttpConfiguration httpConfig)
    {
        WebApiCorsConfiguration corsConfig = new WebApiCorsConfiguration();

        corsConfig.RegisterGlobal(httpConfig);

        corsConfig
                .ForResources(new string[] { "Industries", "Projects" })
                .ForOrigins(new string[] { "http://dev-01", "http://dev-02" })
                .AllowAll();
    }
}
```

Here is the Thinktecture code:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        //CorsConfig.RegisterCors(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        RegisterCors(MvcCorsConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
    private void RegisterCors(MvcCorsConfiguration corsConfig)
    {
        corsConfig
            .ForResources(new string[] {"Industries", "Projects" })
            .ForOrigins(new string[] { "http://dev-01", "http://dev-02" })
            .AllowAll();
    }
```

**Update 2013/04/09:** Neither `context.Response.AppendHeader(...)` nor `context.Response.AddHeader(...)` have any effect. Chrome and FF seem to be OK if they get JSONP regardless of the allow origin header so my project at the very least works. I have also tried `<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>` with no success. I will be deploying the MVC app to a new server to see if it is something localized to the specific machine.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Things worked properly on another server. I ended up creating a CORS proxy for this system as that was easier than deploying it to a new server.

Answer (score 2):

May be, your troubles are due to OPTIONSVerbHandler.
See this link for details:
http://eugeneagafonov.com/post/38312919044/iis-options-cors-aspnet-webapi-en

Comment: That is a very good suggestion. I had actually come to that conclusion yesterday and had found that exact article but even with `<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>` none of the headers that I write to the response come out the other side in IIS. I am going to deploy to another server for testing.